# How to save sessions of putty on a local path?

Tags: putty, tags

I want to save the output of the below command:

```
start C:\Users\Desktop\putty.exe -ssh server_ip  -l username -pw password -m <path of the command file>
```

I used the "`> <output_file>`" at the end of the above command but it didn't work out.

How to get the logs saved in a file ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023920/how-to-export-putty-sessions-list

Answer (score 0):

Once you redirect the output, like so:
`ls > output.txt`

Perform `pwd`, `output.txt` will get stored in the present working directory.

If you want to store in local system then go to `Settings -> Session -> Logging -> log file name`.

You can store the complete session in the file in your local system